# How to replace lambda and grouping to increase performance with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, datetime, dataframe

Perhaps my question looks complicated, but simple in essence. I am new at Python and now I am facing with the problem of too slow code. Below is an optimized version of the code. I would be grateful for a small code review and recommendations on how to speed it up. I think that the slowest operations are `.apply(lambda` and grouping, but I don’t know how to replace them.

```
...
for raw_file in raw_files:
    reader = pd.read_csv(raw_file, chunksize=100000)
    for chunk in reader:
        processed_data = task(chunk)
        for name, data in processed_data:
            save_data(name, data) # some method which saves DataFrame correctly
...


def task(data):
    data = data[data['Quantity'] != 0] # remove zero items
    # add date parts as columns
    data[['dt_year', 'dt_month', 'dt_day', 'dt_day_of_year', 'dt_day_of_week', 'dt_hour']] = \
                data.apply(lambda df: to_date_parts(df['SalesDate']), axis=1)
    # group by location-item to aggregate in different files
    grouped = data.groupby(['LocationID','ItemID'])
    result = []
    for name, group in grouped:
        result += [(name, group)]
    return result



def to_date_parts(str_date):
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(str_date.split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dt_year = date.year
    dt_month = date.month
    dt_day = date.day
    dt_day_of_year = date.toordinal() - dt.datetime(date.year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
    dt_day_of_week = date.weekday()
    dt_hour = date.hour
    return pd.Series([dt_year, dt_month, dt_day, dt_day_of_year, dt_day_of_week, dt_hour])
```

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for help on your *y* solution but do not describe the *x* problem. Please provide background and overall picture of your situation including sample data and output to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python `datetime` vs Pandas `datetime`

There are two interlinked reasons you see poor performance:

1. You use Python built-in `datetime` objects, instead of an efficient Pandas `datetime` series to store dates.
2. You use Python-level `for` loops, instead of vectorised operations supported by Pandas `datetime` series.

So first convert your series to a Pandas `datetime` series:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['SalesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SalesDate'], format=date_format, errors='coerce')
```

Then extract attributes directly from your series:

```
from operator import attrgetter

# list attributes
fields = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'dayofyear', 'dayofweek', 'hour']

# extract attributes
attributes = pd.concat(attrgetter(*fields)(df['SalesDate'].dt), axis=1, keys=fields)

# join attributes to dataframe
df = df.join(attributes)
```

#### Pandas `GroupBy` objects

This concatenation of items to `list` is needless:

```
grouped = data.groupby(['LocationID','ItemID'])
result = []
for name, group in grouped:
    result += [(name, group)]
return result
```

Since `data.groupby(...)` is an iterable, you can just `return` the `GroupBy` object:

```
return data.groupby(['LocationID','ItemID'])
```

Comment: I need to try this out. Thanks. I'll update about the result

Comment: @AlexanderGoida, Sure, I just fixed a typo and added a bit about `GroupBy`.